# Function as method call parameter

Tags: c#, function, methods, delegates, invoke

I have a simple question that might be easily answerd but an intense use of google didn't bring up an answer to my question. So I appologize if there's the right solution and I didn't see it.

If I have a method call like

```
Object.Add(string text, System.Drawing.Color color);
```

that is adding some text to some object with a specified color, and I want to dynamical change the color, then I can type sth. like

```
Object.Add("I'm a string", SomeBool ? Color.Red : Color.Green);
```

This is pretty helpful but will fail as soon as I want to compare more than just two cases.

What I'm looking for is something like (Pseudocode)

```
Object.Add("I'm another string", new delegate (Sytem.Drawing.Color) 
{
    if (tristate == state.state1) 
    {
        return Color.Blue;
    } 
    else if (tristate == state2)
    {
        return Color.Green;
    }
    // ...
});
```

But no matter what I'm trying it will throw an compiler error.

I tried a lot of google about how to pass a function as a method parameter but what I'll find is lot like

```
public void SomeFunction(Func<string, int> somefunction) 
{ 
    //... 
}
```

which is not my question.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using *dictionaries*, e.g.

```
  private static Dictionary<State, Color> s_Colors = new Dictionary<State, Color>() {
    {State1, Color.Blue},
    {State2, Color.Green},
    {State3, Color.Red},
  };


  ... 

  Object.Add("I'm a string", s_Colors[tristate]);
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution. Like it :)

Answer (score 5):

Just place your logic first:

```
Color color;

if (tristate == state1) 
    color = Color.Blue;
else if (tristate == state2)
    color = Color.Green;
else
    color = Color.Red;

Object.Add("I'm a string", color);
```

The reason your `delegate` solution did not work is simply that `new delegate (Sytem.Drawing.Color) { … }` returns a function delegate which needs to be called first before you get a color value. And since your method requires a color and not a method that returns a color, it is not really helpful.

Depending on how short your logic is you could still use the ternary condition operator here and simply chain it:

```
Object.Add("I'm a string", tristate == state1 ? Color.Blue : tristate == state2 ? Color.Green : Color.Red);
```

This would be equivalent to the above verbose `if/else if/else` structure. But of course, it’s not necessarily more readable, so use with caution and choose the more readable solution.

Comment: Oh well that fits to what I've read somewhere about delegates. It sounds logically that a delegate won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This will let you pass a function to decide the state and pass the color into an action that you can then decide what to do with. In reality the text and color can just be used inside of the Add method and wouldn't need to be returned at all for use but this is just an example that it appears you are looking for. Because you aren't using the text inside of the Add method (in your example any way) I took it out and it can just be used inside of the action, otherwise just add it back and use it inside of the Add method.

```
void Main()
{
    Object.Add(() => SomeState.State2, (col) =>
    {
        Label1.Text = "Your text";
        //Do something with color
        Label1.BackColor = col;
    });

    //example 2
    Object.Add(() => 
       {
          return someBool ? SomeState.State1 : SomeState.State2;
       }, 
       (col) =>
       {
           Label1.Text = "Your text";
           //Do something with color
           Label1.BackColor = col;
       });
}

public static class Object
{
    public static void Add(Func<SomeState> func, Action<Color> action)
    {
        switch(func())
        {
            case SomeState.State1: 
                action(Color.Blue);
                break;
            case SomeState.State2: 
                action(Color.Green);
                break;
            default: 
                action(Color.Black);
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum SomeState
{
    State1,
    State2
}
```